# how to prevent other computers from seeing our network computers through vpn

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy, network-share, windows

We have a local office domain consisting of Windows 7 and XP machines that is running on Windows Server 2008 R2.

We also have users that connect via VPN into our network.

My concern is that when a remote user opens up a folder, the Network section on the left side of the folder shows the remote user all the computer names in our local network.

I would like to go about renaming our computers in the local network with more descriptive computer names, but I do not want the users off-site to be able to see these computer names by simply opening up a folder.  (Granted, they can already do this, but our current naming scheme does not link computer names to users.)  I would like to change our computer names so we can determine which computer belongs to which user more easily IF it can be done securely.

**How can I ensure that our local computer names are not showing up in the Network folder for remote, VPN-connected users?**

My online searches have turned up results where people are advised to turn off Network Sharing and Discovery, but that seems to only ensure that the local machine doesn't see other computer names.  I want to prevent OUR computer names from showing up on OTHER computers, and I can't go into the VPN-connected computers and turn off THEIR Network Discovery settings.  I would think there is a group policy that would control this but I have not found one yet and I don't know how I would apply it to VPN-connected computers.

Thanks!

EDIT: That's true, a Group Policy wouldn't run on users only connecting via VPN, good point.  What about a VPN/router policy, then?

Comment: `1.` How would a Group Policy setting affect a machine not joined to your domain? `2.` Security through obscurity isn't security. `3.` If you make sure that your computers and network are appropriately secured then you don't need to worry about someone "seeing" them. `4.` Seeing them doesn't proffer access to them.

Comment: Thanks.  I appreciate you answering my questions, as this is a research/learning process for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.  At the very least, someone with access to your network will be able to do a network scan and get the hostnames directly from the hosts.

Host names are public information that aren't secure and can't be secured, so don't put information you want to secure or restrict in a hostname.

Comment: Thanks.  As said above, this is a research/learning process for me, so I appreciate your answer.  (Also, whoever downvoted the question, YES, I did research this question before posting.)